# Mapping type error from JSON to Flutter entity: '(dynamic) => 'News' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>'

Tags: json, flutter, dart, riverpod

I am trying to read JSON file then assign the values into my flutter entity, using riverpod, statenotifier, and freezed for simple API test.

Currently, I get error like this when I parse JSON file and mapping into the entity
`I/flutter ( 7083): type '(dynamic) => 'News' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform'`

Here is my entity that has `fromJson` method with freezed.

```
@freezed
abstract class News with _$News {
  const factory News({
    bool? ok,
    @Default(null) dynamic error,
    Data? data,
  }) = _News;

  factory News.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$NewsFromJson(json);
}
```

This is my part of repository that trying to parse but received error.
`my_data` is correctly parsed and stored, but mapping into my entity `News` has some confilct
as above.

```
final NewsRepositoryProvider = Provider<NewsRepository>((ref) {
  return NewsRepository();
});

class NewsRepository {
  Future<List<News>> getNews() async {
    // parse my local json file
    final my_data =
        json.decode(await rootBundle.loadString('temp.json'));


    try {
      return my_data
          .map((dynamic item) =>
              News.fromJson(item as Map<String, dynamic>))
          .toList();
    } on Exception catch (error) {
      throw Exception('JSON failed: $error');
    }
  }
}
```

when I try to write like below, it returns  `NoSuchMethodError: Class _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic> has no instance method cast with matching arguments.` and obviously it doesn't have a casting method... `

```
    final my_data = json
        .decode(await rootBundle.loadString('temp.json'))
        .cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
```

I am calling all methods from here which is part of my viewmodel.

```
  final LatestFeedRepository _newsRepository;
  final LatestFeedStateNotifier _newsManager;


  Future<void> fetchLatestNews() async {
    try {
      final List<News> newList = await _newsRepository.getNews();
      _newsManager.setNews(newList);
      state = state.copyWith(isLoading: false);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
```

Here is my StateNotifierProvider, I want to call `setNews` with `List<News>` object that should be from parsing operation but currently I do have error I cannot pass the parameter.

```
@freezed
abstract class NewsState with _$NewsState {
  const factory NewsState({
    List<News>? news,
  }) = _NewsState;
}

final newsProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<NewsStateNotifier, dynamic>(
        (_) => NewsStateNotifier());

class NewsStateNotifier extends StateNotifier<NewsState>
    with LocatorMixin {
  NewsStateNotifier() : super(const NewsState());

  void setNews(List<News> news) {
    state = state.copyWith(news: news);
  }
}
```

Comment: I haven't used `freezed` package, but I'm pretty sure you can't use dynamic type without a custom serializer. The easiest way to fix your problem would be to create a class e.g. `NewsError` and specify it as a type of your error field.

Comment: Thanks - if I simply write like this 'News.fromJsom(json.decode(await rootBundle.loadString('temp.json')));', it successfully parse and map into all objects so looks like dynamic type works, but the runtimetype is actually _$News, not obviously List<News>, which I want to return from getNews() method...

Comment: does your error happen in `getNews` method? Having a closer look at the error I think it wants a different signature of `my_data.map` that is something like `my_data.map((String key, dynamic value) => ...)`